# filename in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, xml

Below are the file location and loading of each of the CSS and JS filename.

```
<link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

In XML the filename is entered as such?

```
let data = "";
let url = 'xml/emailtext.xml';
fetch(url).then(response => response.text()).then(data => {
    let parser = new DOMParser();
    let doc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'application/xml');
});
```

In JSON?

```
let strfy = JSON.Stringify('json/file.json');
let json1 = JSON.parse('strfy');
```

Comment: What are you asking? The first code sample uses HTML to load CSS and JavaScript into an HTML document. The second uses JavaScript to load XML from an external server into a string, and parses the string to an XML document. The third throws an error because of a typo (it's `JSON.stringify`, case matters in JavaScript), and a misunderstanding ([`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) takes the object given and returns a string representation of it -- it does not load a file from anywhere....

Comment: `parse` takes the string given to it and parses a JavaScript object from it. It will not evaluate a string as a JavaScript statement, so it won't pull the value of the `strfy` variable.

Comment: But please [edit] your question so that we know what you mean by "the filename is entered as such?"

Answer (score 0):

When reading a json file, you can read the stream with [response.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) instead of `response.text()`. It returns a promise that will resolve to a javascript object or array if the file contains valid json.

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((obj)=>
  {
    console.log(typeof obj); // object (not json anymore)
    console.log(obj);
  });
```

`obj` above is not json; by then it has already been parsed into a javascript object.

Comment: That's great (albeit covered by thousands of answers already) but how does it answer the OP's question? And what is that question?

Comment: Well, he must have thought he didn't need `fetch` for json, but even if a file contains JSON, it still has to be fetched. Neither `JSON.Stringify() nor `JSON.parse()` take a path as an argument. I figured a working example would help him sort that out.